# Js get URL and change its parameters according select form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow form and a Js code to get current urls from "logodiv" divs and append data form submitted by user into url inside that divs:

```
<select id="type1form" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option value="000">000</option>
 <option value="111">111</option>
 <option value="222">222</option>
</select>

<select id="type2form" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
 <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
 <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
</select>

<div id="logodiv">
    <a href="http://test.com/redir.php?"><img src="logo1.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="logodiv">
    <a href="http://test.com/redir.php?"><img src="logo2.jpg"></a>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {

  var mylinks = [];
    var mylogo = document.querySelectorAll("#logodiv");
    for(var j = 0; j < mylogo.length; j++) {
        mylinks[j] = mylogo[j].childNodes[1].href;
    }

  var type1 = document.getElementById("type1form").value;
  var type2 = document.getElementById("type2form").value;

  for(var i = 0; i < mylogo.length; i++) {
    mylogo[i].childNodes[1].href = mylinks[i] + "&type1=" + type1form + "&type2=" + type2form;
   }

}
</script>
```

My problem is in that last loop code, each time I click on form the url is not changed, but it is appended by form data. So instead url becomes like:

```
test.com/redir.php?type1=000&type2=AAA
```

if select fields are clicked twice or more, the url becomes like:

```
test.com/redir.php?type1=000&type2=AAA&type1=111&type2=BBB
```

I want url becames with only last type1 and type2 parameters submitted by user, not appending the parameters at end of url infinitely.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a few modifications to make it work, you can check them here :
https://jsfiddle.net/x07cqd3z/1/

First, id are supposed to be unique, so logodiv is now a class.

Second, you had some error in your code that have been fixed.

My work around is taking the url base everytime (everything before "?") to append the parameter only once.

Code :

```
<select id="type1" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option value="000">000</option>
 <option value="111">111</option>
 <option value="222">222</option>
</select>

<select id="type2" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
 <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
 <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
</select>

<div class="logodiv">
    <a href="http://test.com/redir.php?"><img src="logo1.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="logodiv">
    <a href="http://test.com/redir.php?"><img src="logo2.jpg"></a>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {

  var mylinks = [];
    var mylogo = document.querySelectorAll(".logodiv");
    for(var j = 0; j < mylogo.length; j++) {
        mylinks[j] = mylogo[j].childNodes[1].href;
    }

  var type1 = document.getElementById("type1").value;
  var type2 = document.getElementById("type2").value;


  for(var i = 0; i < mylogo.length; i++) {
    mylogo[i].childNodes[1].href = mylinks[i].substring(0,  mylinks[i].indexOf('?') + 1) + "&type1=" + type1 + "&type2=" + type2;
   }

}
</script>
```